# How to hide and show keyboard on tablets

Tags: java, android

When i run my app on a keyboard phone it works fine and it looks good but when it is run on the tablet the keyboard screen stays up and i want to hide it when i am done with user input. Is there a way to hide/show the keyboard? All relevent answers are appriciated!

Update: i also want to be able to detect weither the keyboard is being shown or not

Comment: check out this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: if you put that in as an answer ill give it to you